# In this case, what's better: classification or clustering?

Tags: classification, cluster-analysis

I collected data from different sources FB, Twitter, Linkedin, then made them in a structured format. As a result now: I'm having a csv file with 10000 rows (10000 person) and the data associated is about their names, age,their interests and buying habits.

I'm really stuck on this step: CLASSIFICATION or CLUSTERING.  For the classification I don't really have predefined classes or a model for my users to classify them.

For clustering: I started calculating similarities and KMeans, but still can't get the result I wanted. How can I decide what to choose before moving on to the next step of Collaborative filtering?

Comment: What would "the result you wanted" be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foremost, you have to understand that `clustering` is a `pre-processing` activity/task. The idea in clustering is to identify objects with similar properties and group them. The clustering process can be understood in terms of cattle-herding. Wherein the jockey herds loose cattle (*read data points*) into groups.

Note: If you are looking at the partitioning clustering algorithm family includes `K-means`, `k-modes`, `k-prototype` etc. The algorithm `k-means` will work only for numerical data. `K-modes` will work only for categorical data and `k-prototype` will work for both numerical and categorical data.

Question: Is the data preprocessed? If the answer is no, then you may try the following steps;

1. Is the data (column values) all categorical (=text) format or numerical or mixed?

   a. If all categorical then discretize or bin or interval scale them.

   b. if mixed, then discretize or bin or interval scale the categorical values only

   c. Perform missing value and outlier treatment for both numerical and categorical data. This will help in retaining maximum variance as well as reduce dimensionality.

   d. Normalize the numerical values to a median of zero.
2. Now apply a suitable clustering algorithm (based on your problem) to determine patterns. Once you have found the patterns, then you may label them. Once the identified patterns are labelled, thereafter or subsequently a classification algorithm can be used to `classify` any new incoming data points into an appropriate class.